# Running code just before keyboard animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a search bar in my app in which I would like some animation to occur just before the keyboard shows up when the focus is placed in the search box. Is there a delegate method I can make use of to intercept before the keyboard is shown?

I am currently running the following code to detect when the UISearchBar has been activated:

```
-(void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    NSLog(@"Begin Editing");
    CGRect newFrame = searchBar.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                      animations:^{
                          searchBar.frame = newFrame;
                          [searchBar layoutSubviews];
                      }
                      completion:^(BOOL finished){
                          NSLog(@"Done!");
                      }
     ];
}
```

Can I delay the showing of the keyboard in anyway? Maybe call a halt to it and then show it in the completion handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add an notification center to you code.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

then declare a method named keyboardDidShow: and add the animation code to it.

there many options available. I guess

```
name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
```

is also available. just check it if its there and it should work.

Cheers happy coding.!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is also `searchBarShouldBeginEditing:`. You can do your animations, then return `YES`.